# How to break text into paragraphs (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm making a text-based game but when I run my code the text isn't broken up into paragraphs, there is no space between the first `print()` command and the one right after it.

I've tried breaking up the text by putting huge spaces between the text in one print command but that is inefficient and makes my code look messy and difficult to work in.

```
if status.lower().strip() == "modest":
    print("#.")
    print("#")
    print("#")
    print("#")
    print("#")
else:
    main()
```

So what I am trying to do is replicate an HTML command `<br>` which can add space between two lines of text. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: How are you generating Python from HTML?

Comment: The closest to a line break in python is  `print()` .By default python considers it as a newline

Comment: @mishsx that's not what `print()` does. By default `print` adds a `\n` to anything that it prints. Just like most modern languages `\n` is a newline in python - not `print()`

Comment: I am trying to do something similar to <br> not generating python from HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use linebreak command `\n` several times as you wish and I suggest you use triple quotes as follows:

```
print("""
    First paragraph \n\n
    Second paragraph \n\n
    ...
    Last paragraph.
""")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just ust `\n` to print new lines

```
print("#.\n\n#\n\n#\n\n#")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the newline character, `\n`, in your print statement:

```
print("This is P1\n")
print("This is P2")
# Output: 
This is P1

This is P2
```

**Alternatively** (and the way I prefer), would be by adding `end="\n\n"` as an argument to the print statement.

Note: By default, a print statement always "has" `end="\n"`.

This would be as follows:

```
print("This is P1", end="\n\n")
print("This is P2")
# Output is the same as above
```

It is also important to mention that the next printed string/paragraph **will not** have a space between P2 and itself because `print("This is P2")` does not have the `end="\n\n"` added as an argument.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have just started my journey with Python and I was looking how to avoid using several prints within an IF and I came across this post. What I did is to simply the sintaxis by removing prints and the line break command. I just followed the advice of using triple quotes:

```
if temperature > 30: 
    print("""
        Hace calor en BA. 
        Tome Agua. 
        Use Sombrero. 
        Ame con libertad. 
        Abrace a su enemigo y quiera a su padre. 
    """)
```

And it seems to work ok:

C:\Users\facundo.pirola\If Statement!.py"

```
    Hace calor en BA. 
    Tome Agua. 
    Use Sombrero. 
    Ame con libertad. 
    Abrace a su enemigo y quiera a su padre.
```

I am sure you have already solved your doubts ( as this post is 2 year old) but in case you find my solution to not work let me know so I can investigate further.

Thank you!